# How to open a link with different proxy IP adresses in python?

Tags: python, proxy

I want to click a link over and over again while different proxies are enabled to trick the host into thinking I am doing it on different IP adresses. What is the simples way to do this in python?

Thanks!

Comment: I really hope you are not writing a spambot.

Comment: @Radomir Dopieralski: No, obviously he wants to make a lot of money with per-click payed ads.

Answer (score 1):

First, get a list of proxies, then use something like

```
import socks
import socket
import urllib2

proxies = ['127.0.0.1:1080', 'someproxy:1888', ... ] # you could load a file here


for proxy in proxies:
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, *proxy.split(':', 1))
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    urllib2.urlopen(URL)
```